# I tried to join kubernetes nodes with master but it shows errors in all 3 nodes. shown in pic

Tags: kubernetes

Every node shows this error while I tried to join those nodes with Kubernetes master. Any suggestion?

[image]

```
[root@kube-node1 ~]#  kubeadm join 10.0.0.50:6443 --token xtalee.aftgxumqvtjtcq56 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:d0f97b9d53be798a6ab871a2fd8271ee6461b9fd6fdc6350eb89ebee98629ac6
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING RequiredIPVSKernelModulesAvailable]: the IPVS proxier will not be used, because the following required kernel modules are not loaded: [ip_vs_sh ip_vs ip_vs_rr ip_vs_wrr] or no builtin kernel ipvs support: map[ip_vs_rr:{} ip_vs_wrr:{} ip_vs_sh:{} nf_conntrack_ipv4:{} ip_vs:{}]
you can solve this problem with following methods:
 1. Run 'modprobe -- ' to load missing kernel modules;
2. Provide the missing builtin kernel ipvs support

[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-bootstrap-kubelet.conf]: /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf already exists
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables contents are not set to 1
        [ERROR Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
        [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Comment: What is the output of `virt-what`? Install it if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 11):

If you're getting the following error because you've already executed the join command on your nodes. Its created your  /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt file even though your node failed to join.

To get rid of this error, execute the "kubeadm reset" command on your node and execute then join command again. This will reset your cluster environment and then when you try joining the node again to the cluster, it will create all the files again.

Answer (score 4):

This error does occur if you run `kubeadm init` and then try to join, because kubeadm creates these files. Especially if this is a new cluster master, which you ran `kubeadm init`.

You may still need to do a `kubeadm join`, in which case you will encounter this scenario. It is [documented](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1128) as an issue. The K8S documentation notes that you can ignore these errors.

As I noted there, you should add the following to your join command:

```
--ignore-preflight-errors='DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-kubelet.conf,Port-10250,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt'
```

You can see a working example I made, running [K8S v1.14.3 here](https://github.com/KptnKMan/rak8s/blob/d76d093e01071b3bb8efb1e94b54cc5e065e493a/roles/master/tasks/main.yml#L97).

As an extra bit, you should disable swap, which will address your 'Error Swap' error (Example [here](https://github.com/KptnKMan/rak8s/blob/d76d093e01071b3bb8efb1e94b54cc5e065e493a/roles/kubeadm/tasks/main.yml#L6)):

```
dphys-swapfile swapoff && dphys-swapfile uninstall && update-rc.d dphys-swapfile remove
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Note that if these are brand new nodes to the cluster, before `kubeadm join`, to delete any I always run:

```
kubeadm reset --force
```

Note: Don't do this ^^ (reset) on your master after you do a `kubeadm init`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @kvaps approach posted on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/975#issuecomment-432158733)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from swap just type this command and rejoin your node

```
sudo su
swapoff -a
```